# exit a iframe from controller in cakephp to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, cakephp, iframe

I have a contact form in a wordpress website written in cakephp (via iframe).
My issue is that I need to redirect to a  wordpress thankyou page once the cakephp form has been submitted. What happens is that the below redirect stays in the iframe in wordpress which is not what I want. Can I redirect to this wordpress page from a cakephp controller and avoid the iframe in wordpress.
My question is about what cakephp code do I use NOT JAVASCRIPT

```
   $this->redirect('http://www.mywebsite.com.au/book-now/thank-you/');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this using some JavaScript within the rendered View:-

```
window.top.location.href = 'http://www.mywebsite.com.au/book-now/thank-you/';
```

Just make sure that Cake only renders the JavaScript when the form has been successfully posted.

Although you state in your question that you do not want to use a JavaScript you have little choice. This cannot be done using CakePHP itself as PHP is run server side not client side.